# How to find stolon version

Tags: docker, version, postgres-10, stolon

Hi I am new to infra related work.

I am asked to copy 0.14.0 version of stolon binary files like `stolonctl, stolon-keeper, stolon-proxy` and `stolon-sentinal` to our postgresHa docker-container.

I created a new container using the files in git hub and got those binaries and used them for my purpose.

Now when I try to find the version by using:
`stolon-keeper --version`.

I get `stolon-keeper version 1beee94295d009c171d89f644c854d464d7b77c8`

I copied the files from  `0.14.0` only.

But now I need to give my docker image to QA people.

How can I find the exact version from the above statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binary files are generated by the CI uppon new releases.

You need to download the available ones directly from the release page assets (e.g., `stolon-v0.14.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz` from [v0.14.0](https://github.com/sorintlab/stolon/releases/tag/v0.14.0)), then the versions should be right:

```
$ stolon-keeper --version
stolon-keeper version v0.14.0
```